# How can we add ability to treeview for expanding all of nodes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

How can we add a node to a treeview that is not leaf. I want to select node type myself. How can I do this?

Comment: Either you don't understand the definition of a leaf, or we don't understand the question. Care to elaborate more?

Comment: I understand the leaf definition, but I want to be able to expand all of nodes in the tree.

Answer (score 0):

A leaf is just a node with no sub-nodes. So if you want a TreeNode instance to not be a leaf, make sure it has children. There's nothing more to it than that.